# What does command line arguments mean in pstree -a option

Tags: bash

When read the manual of pstree

```
 -a     Show command line arguments.  If the command line of a process is swapped  out,  that  process  is
          shown in parentheses.  -a implicitly disables compaction for processes but not threads.
```

I am very confused about 'command line arguments'

Compare the output

```
me@alpha:~$ pstree |head -5
systemd-+-ModemManager---2*[{ModemManager}]
        |-NetworkManager-+-dhclient
        |                `-2*[{NetworkManager}]
        |-accounts-daemon---2*[{accounts-daemon}]
        |-acpid
me@alpha:~$ pstree -a | head -5
systemd splash
  |-ModemManager --filter-policy=strict
  |   `-2*[{ModemManager}]
  |-NetworkManager --no-daemon
  |   |-dhclient -d -q -sf /usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-helper -pf /run/dhclient-wlp3s0.pid -lf...
```

Command lines are composed of function, options and arguments

Say -a show command line arguments, implies that others just show funtions and options, but that is not the case.

What does the command line arguments mean here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Command-line arguments, in general, refers to all arguments after the name of the program being run. For example, in your command `pstree | head -5`, there is one argument to `head` which is `-5`.

In the `pstree` output, the tree consists of a root of either a pid (process ID) or init, and then the tree of children threads. For example, in your output, NetworkManager is a parent process that is running one `dhclient` and 2 `NetworkManager` threads.

Adding the `-a` flag also prints the arguments that were used when each process or thread was started. For example, in your output, we can see that `NetworkManager` was started with one argument `--no-daemon`, and likewise `dhclient` was started with several arguments.

That is all the man page means by "show command line arguments".

Comment: The thing with `pstree` is that for some reason it doesn't always print [all the arguments](https://gist.github.com/x-yuri/541cd710cd46bcd717a514e067af8969).

Answer (score 1):

The arguments are everything that *isn't* the command name itself. For example, in

```
dhclient -d -q -sf /usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-helper -pf /run/dhclient-wlp3s0.pid -lf
```

the arguments are all of

```
-d -q -sf /usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-helper -pf /run/dhclient-wlp3s0.pid -lf
```

These are the values at positions 1 and onwards in the C `argv` array given to the program when it starts, or in [`sys.argv[1..]` in Python](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.argv).

What the `pstree` manual is implying is that **without `-a` it only lists the name of each program** and not any of the other pieces given on the command line. That is what your two examples show: just `ModemManager` is listed in the first version without `-a`, but `ModemManager --filter-policy=strict` in the `-a` version. It doesn't care whether the "arguments" started with `-` or what they represented.

---

Sometimes programs distinguish "options" and "flags" and "arguments" and even "commands" in their documentation, but to the system they are all just arguments. The program gets given all of them together and gets to decide itself what to do with them, and which fit into each category. It can be useful to help a person think about what they're doing, but it's purely informative and not enforced. Since `pstree` has to show *every* program, it can't know how they all think about their command lines and has to be very generic.

In essence the structure of a command line is

```
command-name argument-1 argument-2 argument-3...
```

and those arguments could be `-x` or a sub-command or a path name, and they're all the same until `command-name` sees them and decides what to do. `pstree` sees them all in a raw form and just reports them to you when you ask for them.